# Storing UIPickerView selection into a variable

Tags: swift, uipickerview

How can I store `UIPickerView` selection into a variable?

```
func pickerView(pickerView: AKPickerView, didSelectItem item: Int) {
}

let selected = pickerView(samplePickerView, what goes here?)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you will be holding an array I guess. So let us name it pickerarray and be it a string array.

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView!, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int){
   selected = pickerarray[row] // selected is the variable
}
```

Here you are using the row property of pickerview.

**Edit**
 For your clarification I am entering the whole code

```
import UIKit


class ViewController: UIViewController,  UIPickerViewDataSource,UIPickerViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet var MyPickerView: UIPickerView!
var selected = ""
let words: NSArray = ["Cat", "Chicken", "fish", "Dog",
    "Mouse", "Guinea Pig", "monkey"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    MyPickerView.delegate = self
    MyPickerView.dataSource = self

    selected = words[0] // setting the default value

}
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return words.count
}
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return "\(words[row])"
}
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    selected = words[row] as! String
}
func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
 }
}
```

to access the selected value from pickerview from any function, use

```
let selectedvalue = selected
```

Comment: But say I want to access to the variable selected in another function and have to use: let selected = pickerView(samplePickerView, ________) what would I pass to the function to get back the selected row.. (if i pass any Int it will just give me back the index of the int)

Comment: @user3773060 I have explained above. Please see that.